# Display set amount of items from XML - Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, load

Edit: I managed to get the latest 10 items because of Brandon's example. But now something else happens.
Before I added the code to only load 10 items, clicking on an item would hide everything except the clicked item and than show the video that is connected to it. Now that I added the piece of code, the content does not show up anymore when clicked on an item. I tried to find out if it's because there's something wrong with closing tags or something, but I can't figure it out.

So it's from the `function itemClick(){` part.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.flabber.nl/rss/nakko/webzap",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
            var $items = $(xml).find('item');
                for(var i = 0; i < $items.length && i < 10; i++){
                var myObj = $items.eq(i);
                    var urllist = myObj.find('link').text();
                    var node = urllist.substring(urllist.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
                    var id = node;
                    var video5 = myObj.find('hosted-video-url').text();
                    var playvid5 = "playVideo('video5')";
                    playvid5 = playvid5.replace("video5", video5);
                    var title = myObj.find('title').text();
                    var url = myObj.find('link').text();
                    var brief = myObj.find('teaser').text();
                    var long = myObj.find('lees-verder').text();
                    var ytube = "";
                    var src = myObj.find('iframe').attr('src');
                    var match = /embed\/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/.exec(long);
                    if(match) ytube = match[1]; // Found it!
                    var playytube = "playVideo('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytube')";
                    playytube = playytube.replace("ytube", ytube);
                    var pubDate = myObj.find('pubDate').text();
                    var img = myObj.find('image').text();
                    $('<p class="items" class="click_'+id+'" id="link_'+id+'" style="width:100%"></p>').appendTo('.class2');
                    $('<div class="terug" style="margin-bottom: 1px; margin-left: 1%"><img src="images/terug.png"></div>').appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    $('<h2 class="title_list" style="padding-top: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #72b252;"></h2>').html(title).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    $('<div class="introtekst"><a href="#"></a></div>').html(brief).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    $('<div class="screenshot"></div>').html('<img src="'+img+'" height="120"/>').appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    $('<h2 class="title"></h2>').html(title).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                    $('.terug').hide();

                        function itemClick(){
                    $('.items').hide();
                        $('.terug').show();
                        $('#link_'+id).unbind('click');
                        $('<div class="introtekst_gal"><a href="#"></a></div>').html(brief).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                        $('<div class="html5vid"></div>').html('<a href="#" onclick="'+playvid5+'"><img src="'+img+'" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"/><div class="play"><img src="images/play.png" /></div></a>').appendTo('#link_'+id);
                        $('<div class="content"></div>').html('<a href="#" onclick="'+playytube+'"><img src="'+img+'" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"/><div class="play"><img src="images/play.png" /></div></a>').appendTo('#link_'+id);
                        $('<div class="openbrowser" id="link_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'"><img src="images/naarf.png" /></a>').appendTo('#link_'+id);   
                        $(this).toggle();
                        if (video5 == ""){
                                                $('.html5vid').remove();
                                                $('.screenshot').hide();
                        }
                        else {
                                                $('.content').remove();
                                                $('.screenshot').hide();                                                    
                        }
                        };



                    $('#link_'+id).bind('click', itemClick);                        

                    $('.terug').mousedown(function(){
                    $(".items , .screenshot").show();                       
                    $(".content , .openbrowser , #videoplayer-0 , #videoplayer-1 , .html5vid , .introtekst_gal" ).remove();
                    $(".terug").hide();
                    $('#link_'+id).bind('click', itemClick);                                                                        

                    });

                    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function () {   
                        $(".items , .screenshot").show();
                        $(".content , .openbrowser , #videoplayer-0 , #videoplayer-1 , .html5vid , .introtekst_gal").remove();
                        $(".terug").hide();
                        $('#link_'+id).bind('click', itemClick)
                    }, false); 

                };


            }

        }); 

    });
```

Comment: Can you post the XML as well, so we can see how it's structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any control over the returned XML, I would recommend you limit the amount of items returned there. You'll get better performance since you won't need to transfer all n items when you only needed 10.

If that's not possible then a classic for loop should suffice to limit the number of processed items.

```
//...            
success: function(xml) {
    var $items = $(xml).find('item');
    for(var i = 0; i < $items.length && i < 10; i++){
        var myObj = $items.eq(i);
        var urllist = myObj.find('link').text();
        var node = urllist.substring(urllist.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
        var id = node;
        var video5 = myObj.find('hosted-video-url').text();
        var playvid5 = "playVideo('video5')";
        //...
    }
}
//...
```

​

Comment: Hi Brandon.

Thanks, that worked! I don't have control over the XML, so I used your code.
Is it also possible to add a "load more" button/link? I was thinking of a function that would change the "< 10" to "< 20", is that a possibility?

Comment: Glad I was able to help! I'm sure your proposal is possible, but since you already have the first 10 you'll want something like `for(var i = 10; i < $items.length && i < 20; i++)`. That way you can load more without have to re-load items you already have. You'll just need a way to supply the value for `i` and `10` based on the context (first load or load more).

Comment: Hi Brandon,

I'll look into that some other time. My internship is coming to an end this week and the "load more" function is not mandatory.
I'm going to update my question now, because content that's loaded when clicking on an item, is not displayed now. Maybe you can help me :)